# Joomla 3.5, Cache Breaking JavaScript Inclusion For Contact Form Plugin

Tags: caching, joomla

Since, I believe, the 3.5 update a site I manage has exhibited some odd behavior. One of the issues is the [Custom Contact Form Plugin](https://github.com/betweenbrain/Custom-Contact-Form-Plugin/tree/amphenol-sensors) (this Advanced Sensors branch was written specifically for the site) is having trouble including some JavaScript it needs.

As seen in the plugin's base file...

```
/**
 * Defer loading of JS until later in the execution cycle
 */
function onBeforeRender()
{
    $this->doc->addScript(JURI::base(true) . '/media/plg_customcontactform/js/form-actions.min.js');
}
```

When "Conservative caching" is enabled (as it has been for years) the JavaScript file is included only on the initial load. Subsequent page refreshes do not include the file in the list of resources at the top of the page.

After not finding anything on here or in Google searches (nor in the list of issues for the project) I started throwing proverbial darts at the code with no success. The creator of the plugin has been away from Joomla for a while so I thought I'd see if anyone here has more knowledge of the inner workings of Joomla and can help me sort this out. For now I have caching disabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having exactly the same problem, I'm using a RSForms Pro, and the forms are added to pages via modules. After pinpointing that the cause as was related to caching the solution was easy enough:
module manager > module > advanced > caching > no caching

You mention you're using a plugin so you have less control unfortunately.

One option could be a caching component or plugin like [JotCache](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jotcache) or [CacheContol](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/cachecontrol), both of which will give you greater control of what get's cached

Or if you have enabled
extensions > plugins > System - Page Cache
you can specify menu items or page urls which you don't want to be cached, this might work. These options are new, and are included with recent Joomla updates.

Good luck!

Comment: Correct on the module vs plugin scenario. I have another plugin by the same developer that's more complex and includes a module with similar functionality. That one is working fine. From what I've read it sounds like things like module caching primarily work with the site-wide cache (what I used to use) and not the Page Cache plugin. Are you aware if that's true? I did enable the page cache plugin, and along with the JavaScript properly being loaded, the site seems to be functioning properly (I also upgraded to Joomla 3.6.0 before testing).  Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Vagari, to clarify, on the site where the form plugin isn't working well, have you enabled Plugins > System - Page Cache ?

Comment: Yes, I left the cache off in system config and enabled the Plugins > System - Page Cache plugin. And then obviously turned off caching on the misbehaving page via that plugin.

Comment: @Vagari, the symptoms you describe are very similar to what I experienced, first that forms which had worked flawlessly stopped working (with conservative caching enabled) and then enabling Plugins > System - Page Cache and trying to exclude the form URLs still didn't work (In Joomla 3.5) .As I mentioned above, my solution was to use conservative caching with, load the form via a module with no caching.  Perhaps you could try JotCache or CacheControl?

Comment: Ahh, I see, I'll keep that in mind. For me the only issue was the JavaScript inclusion. No reports so far of the forms themselves failing.

Comment: @Vagari, I've been working on this some more, if it's still a problem for you I think your best chance is to try using Plugins > System - Page Cache and Global Configuration > System > Cache > Conservative Caching as you have in the past, and then use the CacheControl extension I mentioned above and specify the page(s) which you don't want to be cached.

Comment: Thanks @david-taiaroa, so far simply using Plugins > System - Page Cache by itself seems to be working. I'll keep the other plugins in mind. But for now I'm leaving the Conservative Caching disabled. I'll mark your response as the answer even if we're working in more of workaround territory.

Comment: Thanks @Vagari, if you have any more discoveries, please post a comment. I'm interested in anything else you find out.

Comment: Just to follow up quickly, the [issue I created in the Joomla GitHub repo](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/11203) had a different workaround. To move the code to `onContentPrepareForm` and prepend `JHtml::_('jquery.framework')`. Someone then conceded it _may_ be a bug they couldn't confirm it. The workaround moves the Javascript declaration above everything other than the jQuery declarations.

Comment: Interesting suggestions on the GitHub thread you opened @Vagari.  I'll continue tor follow it. Thanks for the update.